# How to install libgcrypt.so.11 on fedora 22

Tags: fedora, yum

Hi guys is it still possible to install libgcrypt.so.11 on fedora 22 ? 
I followed these [steps](https://support.upwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/211064108-Install-on-Linux) and I get nothing.

1. `yum install yum-plugin-copr`
2. Go to https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/red/libgcrypt.so.11/
3. Find the red-libgcrypt.so.11-fedora-rawhide.repo link under the "Yum Repo"bold header
4. Copy the text and as root, paste it into the file:

   /etc/yum.repos.d/red-libgcrypt.so.11-fedora-rawhide.repo
5. `sudo yum install libgcrypt.so.11`

The output:

```
 Yum command has been deprecated, redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf install libgcrypt.so.11'.
See 'man dnf' and 'man yum2dnf' for more information.
To transfer transaction metadata from yum to DNF, run:
'dnf install python-dnf-plugins-extras-migrate && dnf-2 migrate'

Warning: failed loading '/etc/yum.repos.d/red-libgcrypt.so.11-fedora-rawhide.repo', skipping.
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:10:13 ago on Wed Oct 28 16:44:05 2015.
No package libgcrypt.so.11 available.
```

Comment: `failed loading '/etc/yum.repos.d/red-libgcrypt.so.11-fedora-rawhide.repo'` this probably means there is an error in the file

Answer (score 5):

You should use `dnf` in Fedora 22 because it is the default package manager and old `yum` is deprecated.

`dnf` has a plugin to manage COPR repositories. You shoud enable the COPR repo in the following way:

```
$ sudo dnf copr enable red/libgcrypt.so.11
```

and after that install the package:

```
$ sudo dnf install compat-libgcrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

As an up-to-date answer for Fedora 29/30, I was getting `GCRYPT_1.2 missing`, you can do

`$ dnf install libgcrypt11`

or download an openSuse RPM such as this one:

ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/bosconovic:/branches:/home:/elimat:/lsi/openSUSE_Leap_15.1/x86_64/libgcrypt11-1.5.4-lp151.23.29.x86_64.rpm